# WatchDog control (MAX6369KA+T) with a Microcontroller (Atmega328P)

Tags: atmega

There is a hardware watchdog [MAX6369KA+T](https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX6369-MAX6374-962281.pdf), which has the functions of setting the standby time and enable / disable via contacts (SET0 / SET1 / SET2).

At the moment, I control them using external transistors S9018.

Using transistors slightly increases the size of the circuit.

Tell me, will it be the right decision to remove the transistors and connect the control pins directly to the microcontroller? The maximum current of each contact of the microcontroller is 25 mA. Are any limiting resistors needed for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't expect WDG pins to consume any substantial current. What does the datasheet say?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, thanks for the answer!

Logic input current: 10nA. 
If so, do I need to directly connect the IO of the controller with the SET pins of the WDT? No need to put resistors?

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do. You may want to put zero-Ohm resistors if this is a prototype and you want to be able to rework it if needed, but for a finished product I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Okey, thank you!